# Symfony2 doctrine FindOneOrCreate

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

With propel we have  **findOneOrCreate()**

Example.

```
$bookTag = BookTagQuery::create()
->filterByBook($book)
->findOneOrCreate();
```

In doctrine anywhere in the controller We can do something like that.

```
...................
       $filename='something';
       $document_exists = $em->getRepository('DemoBundle:Document')
                ->findOneBy(array('filename' => $filename));

        if (null === $document_exists) {
            $document = new Document();
            $document->setFilename($filename);
            $em->persist($document);
            $em->flush();
        }
```

Is there another way to achieve this in Doctrine?

Is it OK to call the  Entity Manager inside the Entity Repository?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way is to extend the base repository:

```
// src/Acme/YourBundle/Entity/YourRepository.php
namespace Acme\YourBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class YourRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findOneOrCreate(array $criteria)
    {
        $entity = $this->findOneBy($criteria);

        if (null === $entity)
        {
           $entity = new $this->getClassName();
           $entity->setTheDataSomehow($criteria); 
           $this->_em->persist($entity);
           $this->_em->flush();
        }

        return $entity
    }
}
```

Then tell your entity to use this repository or extend in even further for specific entities:

```
// src/Acme/StoreBundle/Entity/Product.php
namespace Acme\StoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\YourBundle\Entity\YourRepository")
 */
class Product
{
    //...
}
```

and use it in your controller:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$product = $em->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product')
              ->findOrCreate(array('foo' => 'Bar'));
```

Source: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes

Just be aware of that `flush` inside the repository as it would flush all unsaved changes in the EntityManager this way.

Comment: This worked. But how is it possible to call the entity manager inside the repository like that.

Comment: See @nifr's comment: The repository gets initialized with the entity manager. It has to have it... otherwise it couldn't run any queries. You can also use `$this->getEntityManager()` instead of accessing the protected variable directly.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the constructor of `Doctrine\ORM\Repository` [here](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php).

The `EntityManager` is mandatory for constructing a repository. The manager can - by default - not be accessed directly from a repository object because the property `_em` and the getter function `getEntityManager` are `protected`.

but ... yes, sure it is "OK" to call the `EntityManager` via the `_em` property inside a repository. All the other methods like `findBy`, ... etc. use it aswell and need the entity-manager to work actually :)

```
/**
 * @var EntityManager
 */
protected $_em;

public function __construct($em, Mapping\ClassMetadata $class)
{
    $this->_entityName = $class->name;
    $this->_em         = $em;
    $this->_class      = $class;
}

/**
 * @return EntityManager
 */
protected function getEntityManager()
{
    return $this->_em;
}
```

You can easily add a `findOneOrCreate` method to your entity repository or create a generic extended repository including that method.

then you can extend this new base repository whenever you need the method in a concrete entity repository.

Comment: I get this error at the _construct() function. I must be missing something else? "Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\DemoFileRepository::__construct() must be an instance of Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Mapping\ClassMetadata, instance of Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata"

Comment: Change the parameter type to `ClassMetaData` and add a `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping` statement. Otherwise it's looking in your namespace for the class.